Text inside Overbracket?
I'm trying to recreate the following graphic:

Here's what I've been able to create:

Is there anyway I can get the overbracket to overlap the 3? Or put the three inside the bracket another way?
Here is the current code:
$\overbracket[1pt][2pt]{\hbox{\tri{ye}a | and the |}}$

With \tri being defined as:
\newcommand{\tri}[1]{$\stackrel{\textit{3}}{\textrm{#1}}$}


it would (always) be much easier to answer if you provided a small test file that produced the output rather than fragments with undefined commands, \overbracket is not defiend by default for example.  But \smash{\tri{ye}} would hide the height and prevent it raising the overbracket

My apologies, I’ll rectify that the next time I post. Irregardless, your solution worked a treat, thank you!

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tri}{sm}{%
  \shortstack[b]{\scriptsize\IfBooleanT{#1}{\vphantom{x}\smash}{\textit{3}}\\#2}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\textoverbracket}{m}{%
  $\overbracket[1pt][2pt]{\text{#1}}$%
}

\begin{document}

\textoverbracket{\tri{ye}a | and the |}
\textoverbracket{\tri*{ye}a | and the |}

\end{document}


